# using makefile in QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I have a C++ project which uses Makefile,now i want to use QT creator for development but I do not want to touch the Makefile, Is there any way QT creator with an existing Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a new QT Creator project, you are able to edit the make file in the program.

I haven't not had any trouble with adding in my own files, libraries ect. into it, from another, non-QT project.

If you want to avoid the make file all together there is an import function in the GUI to bring in outside files, but I would keep an eye on what it is doing. I have had it make 'creative' choices on what to do with files.

Edit To Include Answer: You can change the exact steps that are used to make the project in the project tab on the left side.

Comment: The strangest "feature" of QT Creator is that it can not parse Qt classes (At least the version I tried). It auto completed all my classes, but none of their classes

Comment: right now i'm just able to use QT creator as another text editor, without being able to build from within QT. is there any facility to configure QT creator to invoke a particular command when i click Build(or ctrl+B)?

Comment: This may be a little slow but on the projects tab on the left side, you can configure the exact steps that are used to build your project.

Comment: @Adam I think your comment is the answer. Thanks.